# Borel Measure of Matrix Groups

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, measure-theory, borel-sets

Viewing the set of matrices $M_n (\mathbb{R})$ as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, I was wondering what was known about the Borel measure of standard matrix sets, such as $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$,  $O_n$, etc. The same question also goes for $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, and e.g. the unitary matrices $U_n$ and hermitian matrices.

Are these sets all measure zero?

Comment: The general linear group has Lebesgue measure $\infty$. The others you are talking about have measure 0 indeed.

Comment: Except for $GL$, these are all defined to be the zero set to some polynomial equations on the entries and therefore [must have measure zero](https://mathoverflow.net/q/25513/34894).

Comment: thank you both!